# Automating entitlement Management

Tags: apex, trigger, service-cloud-console, customer-portal, entitlements

I am working on an entitlement management project and the company wants to make sure that every case has an entitlement process associated to it:

I looked at some of the APEX solutions as seen in this article:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/supercharge-your-service-management-automatically-adding-wagner-/

And a more "Clicks to code" method as seen here:

https://medium.com/@annaloughnancolquhoun/automate-entitlement-insertion-and-milestone-completion-in-salesforce-lightning-experience-9d86d1df94ef

I honestly prefer the "Clicks to code" method as seen in the medium article where she creates a dummy account to represent the entitlement - FYI she does this because all entitlements need to be related to an account. My only fear is that if I take this route of having one generic company associated with an entitlement is that I will end up losing out on standard reporting and/or future standard capabilities.

At this point in time, I do not foresee any issues. Reaching out to anybody here that has experience with the Service cloud - I would love your opinion on this.

Right now we are using email-to-case or web-to-case, so the case does not come in with any accounts if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a potential data skew problem that could occur with the "generic account" you associate all your cases with as the number of cases in your database grows. This could become problematic for you when you need to perform updates or other actions on your database of cases. How problematic this will become will largely depend on your record sharing model for accounts and cases.

As for [entitlement reporting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_impl_report.htm&type=5), when you setup entitlement management, Salesforce automatically creates 4 custom report types for you as follows:

[image: Custom Report Types Screen Capture]

In [Automatically Add Entitlements to Cases from Web, Email, and Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_auto_add.htm&type=5#entitlements_auto_add), Salesforce provides you with all the details and relevant trigger code needed to automatically find a contact's account to find an entitlement to apply it to a Case if it isn't already on the Contact. They provide the same kind of assistance with [Auto-Complete Case Milestones](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_milestones_trigger.htm&type=5#entitlements_auto_add) in the Help.

You'll find these to be "tried and true" solutions that will work smoothly in an org and run much faster on the platform than any kind of Process Builder solution or one that potentially causes a data skew because of having altered your data structure; something I'd avoid doing if at all possible.

Comment: There's a potential data skew problem that could occur with the "generic account" you associate all your cases with as the number of cases in your database grows. - I cannot think of any situation where the association with a generic account would cause any issues.

Comment: All contacts get associated with the same account (becoming children) and all cases become associated with the same account as well. Only 1 user can own that account. Before long, you'll have over 10,000 records associated with the same account/user. This creates a potential race condition & data skew when that happens. See [Parent-Child Data Skew](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_parent_child_data_skew.htm).